# how to show custom confirmation alert in loop for react JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, async-await

**Problem:**

I am uploading files using "react-dropzone" and showing confirmation alert using "react-confirm-alert" if image name is already exist. 
i have to verify image name duplication and show confirmation in loop but it only run one time.

**Need:**

I have to show confirmation alert in loop.

**Issues:**

In this example i am using async/await to show confirmation in loop.
its showing in loop but data from replaceImageAlert() is undefined.
please suggest better place or better solution
this example is working fine with window.confirm() but i have to use custom confirmation box.

```
...
async replaceImageAlert(index, fileObject){
  await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    confirmAlert({
      title: 'Confirm to update old image',
      message: 'Are you sure to do this.',
      buttons: [
        {
          label: 'Yes',
          onClick: () => {
            resolve(true);
          }
        },
        {
          label: 'No',
          onClick: () => {
             resolve(false);
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  });
}
...
async function abc(){
  for (var i =0; i < accepted.length; i++){
    var chechAndRemoveDuplicate =  HF.removeDuplicateImage(accepted[i], this.props.files);
    if (chechAndRemoveDuplicate.duplicate){
      var temp = accepted[i];
      var cb = await this.replaceImageAlert(i, temp);
      console.log('cb', cb);
    }else {
      generateFile(i, accepted[i]).then((value)=>{
          this.props.setResourceFile(value.fileObject); //add file data to file aray
      });
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: "*but data from `replaceImageAlert()` is undefined*" - can you be more specific what the error is, please?

Comment: Notice you will probably want to `await` the `generateFile(…)` call as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `replaceImageAlert` method just waits for the promise, but it doesn't do anything with the result value, and it doesn't `return` anything. You will want to use

```
replaceImageAlert(index, fileObject){
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
//^^^^^^
    confirmAlert({
      title: 'Confirm to update old image',
      message: 'Are you sure to do this.',
      buttons: [
        {
          label: 'Yes',
          onClick: () => resolve(true)
        },
        {
          label: 'No',
          onClick: () => resolve(false)
        }
      ]
    });
  });
}
```

So that when you do `const x = await replaceImageAlert(…)`, the `x` will actually be `false` or `true`.

Comment: correct answer work for me but one thing is confusing me this solution i have tried but didn't work just because i didn't make const x i was creating var x.

Comment: @hu7sy Doing `var` or `const` doesn't really matter here.

Answer (score 0):

The `await` keyword is meant to be used inside an `async` function. To solve your issue you need to declare your functions as:

```
function replaceImageAlert() {
    return new Promise(/* ... */);
}

async function abc() {
    // some code
    await replaceImageAlert();
}
```

Comment: thanks i have update my question i have add it in async function but still didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Do you still get the same error after adding the `async` keyword? Please edit your question with the latest updates.

Comment: @hu7sy the `async` keyword should go to the `abc` function, not the `replaceImageAlert`, just as suggested by my solution.

Comment: i have update my question as you suggest but also i have to add async/await with replaceImageAlert() its showing in loop but returned value from replaceImageAlert() is undefined.

Comment: That's not needed, just remove the `async` keyword from `replaceImageAlert` and replace `await` in it by `return`. I'll update my answer.